# How to load images with Python?

Tags: python, sprite

I have tried to load custom sprites I have made and nothing is working!
My error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\BenPa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Testing pygame.py", line 5, in <module>
    WalkRight = pygame.image.load("./Python38/RPGsprites/RPGsprite_1.png")
pygame.error: Couldn't open ./Python38/RPGsprites/RPGsprite_1.png
```

My code is:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,800))

pygame.display.set_caption("A RPG Game")

WalkRight = pygame.image.load("./Python38/RPGsprites/RPGsprite_1.png")

WalkLeft = pygame.image.load("./C:/Python38/RPGsprites/RPGsprite_4.png")

WalkIdle = pygame.image.load("./C:/Python38/RPGsprites/RPGsprite_0.png")

Background = pygame.image.load("./C:/Python38/RPGsprites/BackGround.png")
```

Please help!

Comment: You are on Windows, right?

Comment: I see that you haven't included the directory in WalkRight's path. Did you try using absolute paths? Ex. load("C:/Python3.8/RPGsprites/...png").

Answer (score 0):

A problem is your path, it should be `WalkRight = pygame.image.load("C:/Python38/RPGsprites/RPGsprite_1.png")` and i think you should use python 3.7 or lower to make sure compatible  with pygame.